# duplicating line in a table and duplicating table

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

My example is  here : http://jsfiddle.net/ranell/J9ZGu/9/

I'm trying to :
-duplicate a line in a table
-duplicate a table with another link for duplicating line in the new table

Problem:
-the new link duplicate a line in te old table
-the new line duplicated contain te same value than the last line

is there an easier method??
thanks  a lot!

Comment: din get you??? try to explain

Comment: as you see when i try to duplicate a line in the new form, the line is added in the first form not the new one :/

Comment: You should format that code properly.

Answer (score 1):

```
  $('#mydiv').clone(true).attr("id", "mytable"+ i).insertAfter('#mydiv');
```

comment if wrong. You are cloning the #mydiv and adding after itself.`insertAfter('#mydiv');`
so even when new form is created you are still adding after the old #mydiv. What you need is to add after the new form.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the line being added in the first table can be solved like this:

```
    $(document).on('click', '.add_line', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var wrapper = $(this).parents('.wrapper');

        var toClone = wrapper.find('table tr:last');
        toClone.after(toClone.clone(true).attr("id", "champs" + i));
    });
```

link: http://jsfiddle.net/J9ZGu/10/

edit:
Of course, you need to add the class `wrapper` to your first div. Also, add class `add_line` and `add_form` to your "add line" and "and form" links.

Comment: Not bad at all, it is almost what i'm looking for , Thanks:)

i asked my self if it's possible to avoid having the same number of line in each form recently cloned.
Also if it's possible to avoid having the same value than the options selected previously.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please explain more.. I don't understand.

Comment: problem 1: exemple : if i add a line on the first form the number of line become two lines
After that if i add a new form i'll have a form with two lines (it's possible to have a new form with only one line?)


problem 2: exemple : if i select a value in the first form , the new form generated will contain the same value selected in the first form.

I'm sorry if it's not clear.

Comment: Since you're cloning the existing tables, they have the same value. If you want to reset the form to the original one, you should make a hidden table and show it *after* you clone it. Every time you clone, it should clone the hidden one. Secondly, to check that the values are not repeated, you need to check the value of <select> like `$('select').val()`. Maybe put the values in an array for every select, and check for existing value as you push onto the array. Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

You need to select table relatively to the link, for example by using prev() method:

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/ds9Uq/

Answer (score 0):

i think that this exemple is full and very useful and no need to remake it in my way , i'll try to adapt it :) i share :
[here](http://www.mdelrosso.com/sheepit/index.php?lng=en_GB&sec=demo7)

Thanks a lot for your help!